# How to create a multi-layout / multi-pages app without re-rendering header and footer

Tags: vue.js, layout, vuejs2, quasar-framework, quasar

Forgive me for this question, I'm very new to Vue.

Is there a way with Quasar to have the below pages structure?

1. Home Page, route `/`, with no drawers
2. Players Page, route `/players`, with left drawer
3. Teams Page, route `/teams`, with both left and right drawers
4. For all pages I need the same header and footer (a music player) and I don't want to re-rendering them every time I switch pages.

I think I can use the same layout and a lot of `if`s but it seems hacky to me.

Is there a "standard" way to do this in Quasar?

Is there a multi-layout / multi-pages example?

Comment: Have a look at this section of the docs https://quasar.dev/layout/routing-with-layouts-and-pages ... specifically <q-page-container> & <router-view>.

Answer (score 1):

As I know you have two options.

1. Use one layout. Hide right drawer on `/playes` and hide left one on `/teams`.
2. Use two layouts. In each reuse footer and header. Here is how router should look like (router from my app):

```js
const routes: RouteConfig[] = [
  {
    path: '/auth',

    component: () => import('layouts/AuthLayout.vue'),
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: () => import('pages/Auth.vue')
      }
    ]
  },

  {
    path: '/',
    component: () => import('layouts/MainLayout.vue'),
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: () => import('pages/Index.vue'),
      },
    ]
  },

  // Always leave this as last one,
  // but you can also remove it
  {
    path: '*',
    component: () => import('pages/Error404.vue')
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What I don't understand is how to `In each reuse footer and header.`. if I reuse header and footer components Vue re-render them and the music player is reset. Is it more clear now what my problem is?

Comment: Oh, sorry I didn't think about this. Maybe you can try to create a multi-level route with layouts. Like my router example but with 3 levels. 1. Footer and Header, 2. drawer (left or right) and 3. your page

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand what you mean.